# THREE.js imported GLB model sits too high (Y axis) in Cannon body

Tags: three.js, cannon.js

I am new to Cannon and THREE but am learning quickly (and having fun). My issue is that I have to update my models position to match the Cannon box in the animate function BUT it makes it sit too high (50% of it is inside the box and 50% above it). If i try manually adjusting the position.y in the animate loop then once physics takes over they wander out of sync. Is it because my model has its pivot in the center? Any advice greatly appreciated :-)